# How to configure prefix events in S3 for a dynamically named subdirectory?

Tags: amazon-web-services, events, amazon-s3, lambda

So I have an S3 bucket with this structure:

```
    ready_data/{auto_generated_subfolder_name}/some_data.json
```

The thing is, I want to recursively listen for any data that is put after the `ready_data/` directory.

I have tried to set the prefix to `ready_data/` and `ready_data/*`, but this only seems to capture events when a file is added directly in the `ready_data` directory. The ML algorithm might created a nested structure like `ready_data/{some_dynamically_named_subfolder}/{some_somefolder}/data.json` and I want to be able to know about the data.json object being created in a path where `ready_data` is the top-level subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

`ready_data/` is correct.

The "prefix" is a left-anchored substring.  In pseudocode, the test is determining whether `left(object_key, length(rule_prefix)) == rule_prefix` so wildcards aren't needed and aren't interpreted. (Doesn"t throw an error, but won't match.)

Be sure you create the rule matching `s3:ObjectCreated:*` because there are multiple ways to create objects in S3 -- not just `Put`.  Selecting only one of the APIs is a common mistake.